# Not doing anything

Tags: five-precepts, buddha, metta, wisdom

q:

> Is not doing anything in a situation and just being mindful breaking
>   any of the precepts?

Answer (score 1):

In addition, to observe the five precepts Buddha also recommends doing.

Do not kill = Practice loving-kindness

Do not steal = Giving or generosity

Do not indulge in sensual pleasures = Celibacy

Do no lie = Tell the truth

Do not consume alcohol = Practice mindfulness.